# Should I use SASS or SCSS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, sass

Does anyone know if SASS file extension is pretty much deprecated at this point and the SASS project is heading into straight SCSS usage?

I love the terseness of SASS, and want to continue using SASS instead of SCSS, but if the SASS project is geared toward SCSS usage perhaps I should just switch now?

Comment: Comes down to personal preference, really. I liked the terseness of SASS too but ended up adopting SCSS instead. It's easier when switching between it and plain vanilla CSS and I still prefer brackets to whitespace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both are here to stay however various communities (Rails for instance) seem to be leaning towards SCSS.  It is the default in Rails 3.1.

The SASS file extension is by no means deprecated.

> Although no longer the primary syntax, the indented syntax will continue to be supported.

(from http://sass-lang.com/)

Here's a very recent conversation about this topic on the librelist mailing list,
http://librelist.com/browser//nesta/2011/3/18/re-sass-or-scss/#821b93a6e91fee4898aa115a7017407b

If you wish to be on the bleeding edge, it's recommended to switch over to SCSS.

Answer (score 2):

SASS syntax will be fully supported, but going forward go with SCSS